# NVMe on which Ubuntu is installed seems to disappear while running

Tags: ssd, bios, troubleshooting, computer-building, nvme

I made a custom build desktop, which is turned on 24/7 and serves as server. Today I experienced for the second time that the machine turned unresponsive. Hooking up a screen does nothing. Inserting a keyboard did not even caused the LED on the keyboard to light up. However, fans still going and Ethernet connector lights were turned on.

So, I hit the reset button, and immediately the LED on the keyboard lit up and the BIOS displayed its logo on the screen. But then it went straight into the BIOS settings, where it revealed that there were no boot options available. The SSD on which Ubuntu is installed had seemingly disappeared, according to the system, which could explain why the system turned unresponsive, I guess.

I hit the reset button once again, but the same result: no SSD visible.

Then I turned the machine off, and back on (instead of a reset). And the problem was gone: SSD back available and system booting as normal.

Any idea what might be going on?

Specs:

- mobo: ASRock A320M
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700
- SSD: WD SSD Black 256GB M.2
- PSU: Seasonic S12II-Bronze 520W
- GPU: MSI AMD RX550
- OS: Linux 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu

Comment: I am seeing the same symptom as you are with the same motherboard and SSD. I tried disabling APST but I still have the issue. Did you ever figure out what was causing this problem?

Comment: Nope, not yet! So happy to see someone else has the same issue. Slowly we might gain some attention. Feel free to contact me at `<lastname><firstname>@gmail.com` (lastname is Courteaux) with your specs. I'm willing to investigate further.

Comment: I just swapped out the GPU as a test for a GTX 1050 Ti. Still the same. @jholtrop What are your specs?

Comment: I have the ASRock A320M PRO4 motherboard, AMD RYZEN 5 1600, WD Black 256GB, Thermaltake Smart Series 500W, ATI Radeon X600 with Ubuntu 18.04. When I built the machine, Ubuntu 16.04 had too old of a kernel for Ryzen and Ubuntu 18.04 was not out yet. So I ran Fedora Server for a little while. On that OS (which I think was kernel 4.15) I had similar symptoms but different dmesg entries. There it turned out to be a problem with APST. After disabling APST I could run for months without a problem. Then I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and started having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did three things in while trying to solve this:

1. As *@jholtrop* suggested; I disabled the APST (Autonomous Power Saving Transition) by passing following kernel parameter:

   ```
   nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0
   ```

   in the GRUB entries.

   Test if it worked by doing:

   ```
   cat /sys/module/nvme_core/parameters/default_ps_max_latency_us
   ```

   as this should now print `0`.
2. Install the [latest BIOS firmware version from ASRock for my motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/A320M/index.asp#BIOS), as it claimed to "*improve M.2 SSD compatibility*", which seems pretty related.
3. Disabled C-state power saving in the BIOS.